# Cannot add QtWebWidgets to project

Tags: c++, qt

As the title says I can't add QtWebWidgets to any QT project. I'm running QT creator 3.2.0 based on Qt 5.3.1 run in Linux Mint 17. When I add

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

to my .pro file I'm getting a lot of errors, which say that the compiler can't find file here's the compiler output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstapp-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstinterfaces-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstpbutils-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstvideo-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstbase-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgstreamer-0.10
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [web_browser] Error 1
21:24:24: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project web_browser (kit: Desktop Qt 5.2.1 GCC 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

Any ideas what's causing those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Install in Ubuntu (or like)

Install g++

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Install OpenGL libraries

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev -y
```

After perform this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev
```

And

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

### Other distros (like Debian)

After install QT perform this commands in terminal with `su` or `sudo`

First update (with su or sudo):

```
apt-get update
```

After install packages (with su or sudo):

```
apt-get install libxslt
apt-get install libxml2
apt-get install libgio2.0
apt-get install libgstapp0.10
apt-get install libgstinterfaces0.10
apt-get install libgstpbutils0.10
apt-get install libgstvideo0.10
apt-get install libgstbase0.10
apt-get install libgstreamer0.10
apt-get install libgobject2.0
apt-get install libgmodule2.0
apt-get install libgthread2.0
apt-get install libglib2.0
apt-get install libgl
```

Comment: I've tried this but most of the packages are missing, I'm searching for them at the moment.

Comment: I'm running apt-get update at the moment.
BTW If anybody needs to install those packages most of the are missing in the repository I mean they aren't individual packets here's list with all files I downloaded and install to obtain the packages but this haven't fix the problem:
apt-get install libxslt1-dev 
apt-get install libxml2
apt-get install libgio2.0
apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 
apt-get install ia32-libs-gtk
apt-get install libglib2.0-0
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx

Comment: their repositories are modified? Try using the official repositories.

Comment: What you mean by official repositories. I've just install Linux Mint 17 and I didn't chance the repositories I think I'm using Ubuntu repositories

Comment: Added extra for Ubuntu in my answer

Comment: I have all packages you mention

Comment: Install QT with `sudo` or without `sudo`? Install QT in user folder?

Comment: QT is in /opt folder, I don't think there's the problem but I think I found a list with libs I need to install webkit

Comment: I found this `qtbase5-dev`, see answer